# C++ - iteration over a n-ary tree

Tags: c++, loops, tree

This is the function with iteration algorithm over a n-ary tree, given a `name`, and use it to find the parent tree, return `parent tree's data` if found, `"ZERO"` if no parent is found, and `"NA"` if the `name` is not in any tree in the `Tree<string>*` vector. It works most of the time, but will occasionally give wrong output that `"ZERO"`, which a parent was supposed to be found, mostly in the `leaves`.

```
string getSource(const string name) const { // no recursion
    if (existInVector(name, trees)) { // vector of Tree<string>*
        queue<Tree<string>> treesQueue;
        vector<Tree<string>*>::const_iterator it = trees.begin();
        for (; it != trees.end(); ++it) { // for each tree
            treesQueue.push(**it); // push tree
            for (int i = 0; i < (**it).root->numChildren; ++i) // push children
                treesQueue.push((**it).root->children[i]);
            while (!treesQueue.empty()) {
                Tree<string> temp = treesQueue.front(); // pop front
                treesQueue.pop();
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.root->childCount; ++i) { // check
                    if (temp.root->children[i].root->data == name)
                        return temp.root->data;
                }
            }
            if (it == trees.end()-1 && treesQueue.empty())
                return "ZERO";
        }
    }
    return "NA";
}
```

Here is the class template of the tree:

```
template <class T>
class Tree {
private:
    Node<T>* root;
public:
    // ... member functions ...
};

template <class T>
class Node {
private:
    T data;
    int numChildren;
    Tree<T>* children; // Tree<T> array
};
```

What is the possible reason to get the wrong result sometimes?

```
// example with wrong result
Tree<string> tree; // below is what is inside, root is Node "G", "H" is child of "G" and so on
G
\-H
  \-I
    \-J

tree.getSource("J") == "ZERO"; // Supposed to be "I"
```

Comment: It seems you only go 2 levels depth, *"push children"* should probably be in `while (!treesQueue.empty())` (adjusting children to push).

Comment: @Jarod42 Well if I do `// push children` in `while()`, it will be infinite loop, but according to what I found on Google about `BFS algorithm`, it should be in `while()`, this confused me

Comment: You have to push children of `temp`.

Comment: @Jarod42 My idea is: I have a vector of trees, so take care of one at a time. For a tree, I first push root in queue, and push all children. And I do checking on front of the queue. If checking fails, pop and check next subtrees(children of the first tree). Every time I push a tree, subtree will also be pushed, so I think this will not stop until it gets to the bottom. Anyway, it does't work in some cases

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you so much. I forgot to push `temp`'s children and caused the trouble. And could you explain why should we do `// push children` in the while loop? What if I do `// push root's children` right after the `// push root`?

Comment: `treesQueue.push(**it); // push tree` is the initialization, the addition of children should be done on *visited* tree/node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push children of current node/tree you visit.

I also remove some copies.

```
std::string getSource(const std::string& name) const {
    if (!existInVector(name, trees)) { // vector of Tree<string>*
        return "NA";
    }
    std::queue<const Tree<std::string>*> treesQueue;
    for (const auto& tree : trees) {
        treesQueue.push(&tree);
        while (!treesQueue.empty()) {
            const auto& current = *treesQueue.front();
            treesQueue.pop();
            for (int i = 0; i != current.root->childCount; ++i) {
                const auto& child = current.root->children[i];
                if (child.root->data == name)
                    return current.root->data;
                treesQueue.push(&child);
            }
        }
    }
    return "ZERO";
}
```